# It it correct to return non-full resource from the REST API?

Tags: api, rest

I have an example resource which is an offer. Let's assume that every offer has n offer items eg. 5 or 7. These offer items might have different state, for example "Invalid". My problem is that i need to create an endpoint which will return an offer (my resource) with the Invalid offer item for a specific user let's say. From this endpoint it would be much better for me to return the mentioned offer with ONLY invalid offer item (so some of the offer items might be trimmed). The offer must also be returned, not-only the offer item. I wonder is it correct from the REST point of view to return the resource but with no full state. How the example endpoint uri could look like?

Comment: I'm probably not on top of my game today and thus don't understand the question somehow. Is the `offerItem` (some kind of product I guess) state somehow dependent on the user (like in "product is not meant for the user") or what does `Invalid` in that context mean? I also don't really understand why you do want to return an offer with invalid items then. But as a general rule of thumb here: Design the resource and the interaction as if you're dealing with traditional HTML pages. REST just uses the same interaciton concepts as the Web. REST doesn't care about URI design though

Answer (score 0):

Incase if the response wouldn’t always have the complete data, i am assuming you are expecting something like a filter.

If your api is a listing api, you can use a **filter**.
Ex: /users?status=active, which could return only the set of active users.

Else if your api is to return a response of a single object, then you may use a parameter **fields** to return only specific data in the response.
Ex: /users/user_id?fields=email,age